# Get all image paths from a website

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get all image paths of an Instagram page but they seem to block the initial request.
My attempt:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://instagram.com/redbull');
echo $contents;
```

If a service blocks such a request, is it impossible to get the source code of the website or could a different programming language (JS, AS3) work?

Comment: Use Instagram's API instead of trying to scrape the page.

Comment: what would the server care what language you're using. "Oh, this person's using PHP. block them!" "Oh hey, they switched to visual basic, that's a-ok!". if you're being blocked by the service, you're being blocked, and changing languages isn't going to change that fact.

Comment: Really? I just tried AS3 and it loads the source code: `var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
trace(e.target.data);
}
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://instagram.com/redbull"));`

Comment: Was your AS3 test from the same server and IP address as your PHP tests? Likely not, and that would be the difference, not the language of choice.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Do I need users to authorize my app to load the latest ~10 images from their account or is there a way to do it without authorization?

Comment: @Tom: No idea.  Never used their API.  All I know is that's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you just need to set a [User Agent string](http://phpave.com/specifying-a-user-agent-when-using-file_get_contents/), to a standard browser UserAgent string. [Here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) is a list for Chrome:

> http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/